# MongooseJS Find Max, Min and Avg Number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, locomotivejs

I have a MongoDB database containing a series of values including a Number field, I wish to get the maximum number, minimum and average. How is the best way to do this using mongoosejs and nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use "agregation".

Here you can find some examples: [SQL to Agregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

I hope it helps.
Regards,